# In Typescript, how can I make it understand the types when I import by using require()?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using TypeScript in IntelliJ.

Suppose I have this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Then I use it like this:

```
exports.doSomething = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {...}
```

However, it doesn't actually link `https` to anything. It's considered of type `any`. Then it doesn't know the type of `onCall` too.

I found out I can fix this by adding this to the top of the file:

```
import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/https";
```

And then use it like this:

```
exports.doSomething = onCall((data, context) => {...}
```

However, this is not a good solution, since other namespaces may contain `onCall`, and I need to differentiate between them.

So, my question is: How can I make it understand the types when I import stuff using `require()`?

Comment: Have you tried `import functions = require('firebase-functions')`?

Comment: It works. So, instead of `const` I should have used `import`. If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `import name = require ('path')` syntax :

```
 import functions = require('firebase-functions')
```

You can also try

```
import * as functions 'firebase-functions';
```

If you use the appropriate module system the import will get converted to `require`